# Saving multiple plots with for loop. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a list of values I want to plot and save each plot for a separate file. I created a for loop that works just fine for showing plots in IDE, but when I'm trying to save them in separate files I'm running to situation when the first created png file just overwrites with each iteration instead of creating new file.

This is my loop

```py
for name in names:
    DDT = dfs[dfs['Name']== name]
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
    plt.plot(DDT['Time'], DDT['Low'], label = 'Low')
    plt.plot(DDT['Time'], DDT['Heigh)'], label = 'Heigh')
    plt.plot(DDT['Time'], DDT['Average'], label = 'AVG')
    plt.title(name)
    plt.legend()
    y = 1
    plt.savefig("plot{y}.png".format(y=y))
    y+=1
    plt.close()
    # plt.show()
```

The reason I added weird "y" value is that names contain slashes so that program "thinks" it's different folders.  So basically I want to get plot1.png, plot2.ong...plotn.png as a result.

How can I avoid overwriting single created png file and get a separate file for each loop?

Comment: Set `y=1` outside the loop

Comment: @JodyKlymak stupid me. it worked. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

In python there is a built-in solution for indexing loops. You can use `enumerate` for this

```
    for idx, name in enumerate(names):
        DDT = dfs[dfs['Name']== name]
        plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
        plt.plot(DDT['Time'], DDT['Low'], label = 'Low')
        plt.plot(DDT['Time'], DDT['Heigh)'], label = 'Heigh')
        plt.plot(DDT['Time'], DDT['Average'], label = 'AVG')
        plt.title(name)
        plt.legend()  
        plt.savefig("plot{idx}.png".format(idx=idx))
        plt.close()
        # plt.show()
```